# How do I set docker-credential-ecr-login in my PATH before anything else in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, aws-ecr

I'm using AWS ECR to host a private Dockerfile image, and I would like to use it in GitLab CI.

Accordingly to the documentation I need to set docker-credential-ecr-login to fetch the private image, but I have no idea how to do that before anything else. That's my .gitlab-ci file:

```
image: 0222822883.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-build:latest

tests:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo "before_script"
    - apt install amazon-ecr-credential-helper
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - echo "script"
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec rspec
  allow_failure: true # for now as we do not have tests
```

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using AWS ECR with GitLab CI and not with AWS ECS? Or the flip to this question, why can't you put the Docker image into GitLab's private registry?

Comment: Well, historical reasons hahaha

Answer (score 3):

I confirm the feature at stake is not yet available in GitLab CI; however I've recently seen it is possible to implement a generic workaround to run a dedicated CI script within a container taken from a private Docker image.

The template file `.gitlab-ci.yml` below is adapted from the OP's example, using the [Docker-in-Docker](http://blog.teracy.com/2017/09/11/how-to-use-docker-in-docker-dind-and-docker-outside-of-docker-dood-for-local-ci-testing/) approach I suggested in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689194/9164010), itself inspired by the [GitLab CI doc dealing with `dind`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#container-registry-examples):

```yaml
stages:
  - test

variables:
  IMAGE: "0222822883.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-build:latest"
  REGION: "ap-northeast-1"

tests:
  stage: test
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    # GIT_STRATEGY: none  # uncomment if "git clone" is unneeded for this job
  before_script:
    - ': before_script'
    - apt install amazon-ecr-credential-helper
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
    - pip install awscli
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region "$REGION")
    - docker pull "$IMAGE"
  script:
    - ': script'
    - |
      docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/build" -w /build "$IMAGE" /bin/bash -c "
        export PS4='+ \e[33;1m($CI_JOB_NAME @ line \$LINENO) \$\e[0m '  # optional
        set -ex
        ## TODO insert your multi-line shell script here ##
        echo \"One comment\"  # quotes must be escaped here
        : A better comment
        echo $PWD  # interpolated outside the container
        echo \$PWD  # interpolated inside the container
        bundle install
        bundle exec rspec
        ## (cont'd) ##
      "
    - ': done'
  allow_failure: true # for now as we do not have tests
```

This example assumes the Docker `$IMAGE` contains the `/bin/bash` binary, and relies on the so-called [block style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/block/) of YAML.

The above template already contains comments, but to be self-contained:

- You need to escape double quotes if your Bash commands contain them, because the whole code is surrounded by `docker run … "` and `"`;
- You also need to escape local Bash variables (cf. the `\$PWD` above), otherwise these variables will be resolved prior running the `docker run … "$IMAGE" /bin/bash -c "…"` command itself.
- I replaced the `echo "stuff"` or so commands with their more effective [colon](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16) counterpart:

  ```
  set -x
  : stuff
  : note that these three shell commands do nothing
  : but printing their args thanks to the -x option.
  ```

[*Feedback is welcome as I can't directly test this config (I'm not an AWS ECR user), but I'm puzzled by the fact the OP's example contained at the same time some `apt` and `apk` commands…*]

#### Related remark on a pitfall of `set -e`

Beware that the following script is buggy:

```
set -e
command1 && command2
command3
```

Namely, write instead:

```
set -e
command1 ; command2
command3
```

or:

```
set -e
( command1 && command2 )
command3
```

*To be convinced about this, you can try running:*

```sh
bash -e -c 'false && true; echo $?; echo this should not be run'
  → 1
  → this should not be run
bash -e -c 'false; true; echo $?; echo this should not be run'
bash -e -c '( false && true ); echo $?; echo this should not be run'
```

Answer (score 0):

From GitLab documentation. In order to interact with your AWS account, the GitLab CI/CD pipelines require both AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to be defined in your GitLab settings under Settings > CI/CD > Variables. Then add to your before script:

```
image: 0222822883.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api-build:latest

tests:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo "before_script"
    - apt install amazon-ecr-credential-helper
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
    - pip install awscli
    - $( aws ecr get-login --no-include-email )
  script:
    - echo "script"
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec rspec
  allow_failure: true # for now as we do not have tests
```

Also, you had a typo is `awscli`, not `awsclir`.Then add the builds, tests and push accordingly.

Comment: I already had that configured in the environment variables. Sorry for the typo, it is correct in the project though.

Comment: if you want to  pull or push, the command to login to the ECR registries is the same it could be $( aws ecr get-login --no-include-email ) or aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sh

Comment: Could you read the question more carefully? Private ECR images don't work with GitLab CI, the docker-credential-ecr-login command needs to be set somehow.

Comment: Oh im sorry, now i got it, you want to use that image for the build, not build an image and then push to ECR

Comment: This might help https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1583

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have some sort of logic error in the case. `image` in the build configuration is a CI scripts runner image, not image you build and deploy.

I think you don't have to use it in any case since it is just an image which has utilities & connections to the GitLab CI & etc. The image shouldn't have any dependencies of your project normally.

Please check examples like this one https://gist.github.com/jlis/4bc528041b9661ae6594c63cd2ef673c to get it more clear how to do it a correct way.

Comment: you're wrong... the script you sent me is to publish a docker image to ECR, and what I need is to pull an image from ECR. I can without any questions use images from ECR, the problem is I need to first set docker-credential-ecr-login in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using docker executor mode of gitlab runner.

SSH into the EC2 instance showed that `docker-credential-ecr-login` was present in `/usr/bin/`. To pass it to the container I had to mount this package to the gitlab runner container.

```sh
gitlab-runner register -n \
--url '${gitlab_url}' \
--registration-token '${registration_token}' \
--template-config /tmp/gitlab_runner.template.toml \
--executor docker \
--tag-list '${runner_name}' \
--description 'gitlab runner for ${runner_name}' \
--docker-privileged \
--docker-image "alpine" \
--docker-disable-cache=true \
--docker-volumes "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" \
--docker-volumes "/cache" \
--docker-volumes "/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login:/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login" \
--docker-volumes "/home/gitlab-runner/.docker:/root/.docker"
```

More information on this thread as well: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1583#note_375018948

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup where we need to run CI jobs based off of an Image that is hosted on ECR.
Steps to follow:-

- follow this guide here>> https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper
- gist of this above link is if you are on "Amazon Linux 2"

  sudo amazon-linux-extras enable docker

  sudo yum install amazon-ecr-credential-helper
- open the ~/.docker/config.json on your gitlab runner in VI editor
- Paste this code in the ~/.docker/config.json

  {
  "credHelpers":
  {
  "aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
  }
  }
- source ~/.bashrc
- systemctl restart docker
- also remove any references of DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG from your GitLab>>CI/CD>> Variables

That's it

Comment: I still tried this and still getting the same error. I am actually using ec2 spot instances.

Comment: We need to substitute values for `aws_account_id` and `region` right?

Comment: Yes you'll have to replace those values.