# Failing gitlab CI due to "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, raspbian

I'm attempting to have my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file use an image off the Gitlab container registry. I have successfully uploaded the `Dockerfile` to the registry and I can pull the image from the registry on my local machine and build a container just fine. However, when using the image for my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, I get this error:

```sh
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I've seen a bunch of discussion about Windows EOL characters, but I'm running on `Raspbian` and I don't believe that's the issue here. However, I'm pretty new at this and can't figure out what the issue is. I appreciate any help.

`.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```sh
before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

stages:
    - test-version

test:
    stage: test-version
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my/project/test:latest
    script:
        - python --version
```

`test.Dockerfile` (which is in the registry as `registry.gitlab.com/my/project/test:latest`):

```sh
ARG base_img="python:3.6"                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
FROM ${base_img}

# Install Python packages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

Edit:
Another thing to note is that if I change the image in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to just `python:3.6`, then it runs just fine. It's only when I attempt to link my image in the registry.

Comment: If `registry.gitlab.com/my/project/test:latest` is a private Docker image (namely, if `gitlab.com/my/project` is a private repository, do you confirm this?), I am unsure it is possible to use it with the `image:` property; actually the `docker login` you mention in the `before_script:` step won't be executed beforehand anyway, but it will be executed *within the container*.

Comment: It is a private project. I think what you said makes sense then. However, is there a way to use a private projects Docker image for testing instead?

Comment: OK so I've just posted a possible solution for your use-case, relying on the so-called `dind` approach. Feel free to test / vote if the answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed in the comments, `gitlab.com/my/project` is a private repository, so that one cannot directly use `docker pull` or the `image:` property with `registry.gitlab.com/my/project/test:latest`.

However, you should be able to adapt your `.gitlab-ci.yml` by using the `image: docker:latest` and manually running `docker` commands (including `docker login`).

This relies on the so-called [Docker-in-Docker (dind) approach](http://blog.teracy.com/2017/09/11/how-to-use-docker-in-docker-dind-and-docker-outside-of-docker-dood-for-local-ci-testing/), and it is [supported by GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#container-registry-examples).

> Here is a generic template of `.gitlab-ci.yml` relying on this idea:

```
stages:
  - test-version

test:
  stage: test-version
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    # GIT_STRATEGY: none  # uncomment if "git clone" is unneeded
    IMAGE: "registry.gitlab.com/my/project/test:latest"
  before_script:
    # - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
    # or better
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin "$CI_REGISTRY"

  script:
    - docker pull "$IMAGE"
    - |
      docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/build" -w /build "$IMAGE" /bin/bash -c "
        export PS4='+ \e[33;1m(\$0 @ line \$LINENO) \$\e[0m '  # optional
        set -ex  # mandatory
        ## TODO insert your multi-line shell script here ##
        echo \"One comment\"  # quotes must be escaped here
        : A better comment
        python --version
        echo $PWD  # interpolated outside the container
        echo \$PWD  # interpolated inside the container
        ## (cont'd) ##
      " "$CI_JOB_NAME"
    - echo done
```

This leads to a bit more boilerplate, but this is generic so you can just replace the `IMAGE` definition and replace the `TODO` area with your own Bash script, just ensuring that the two items are fulfilled:

- If your shell code contains some double quotes, you need to escape them, because the whole code is surrounded by `docker run … "` and `"` (the last variable `"$CI_JOB_NAME"` is a detail, it is optional and just allows one to override the `$0` variable referenced within the Bash variable `PS4`)
- If your shell code contains local variables, they need to be escaped (cf. the \$PWD above), otherwise these variables will be resolved prior running the `docker run … "$IMAGE" /bin/sh -c "…"` command itself.