# How to run a mounted shell-script inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a mounted shell-script inside a docker container by following these steps:

1. **build stage:** build the docker image.
2. **test stage:** mount a directory into the container at runtime with a shell-script file inside.
3. **test stage:** run the shell-script file from inside the docker.

could someone please explain how this should be done?

**see line:** `#- ?? HERE I SHOULD RUN THE TEST: /test/check.sh ??`

```
services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - build
    - test

before_script:
        - docker info

# Build the docker image
build:
    image: docker:latest
    services:
        - docker:dind
    before_script:
        - docker login docker.example.com -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - docker build -t our-docker .
        - docker save our-docker > our-docker.tar
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - our-docker.tar
        expire_in: 1 week

    stage: build


test:
    image: docker:latest
    only:
        - master
    script:
        - docker load < our-docker.tar
        - docker run --volume source="$(pwd)/test",target="/test" our-docker
        #- ?? HERE I SHOULD RUN THE TEST: /test/check.sh ??
    stage: test
```

Comment: You want to run a test-is the script available inside the container? Did you face any errors in accessing ?

Comment: @salsinga no, the error is the file(check.sh) not exists, when trying to access it after mounting, that's why I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

Comment: it means your script has not been mounted. try with copy command and check if it works and in this way the possibility would be ruled out that there is no other unknown issue

Answer (score 0):

First, there was an issue with the `docker run` command itself:

```
docker run --volume source="$(pwd)/test",target="/test" our-docker  # buggy
```

as the syntax to setup a [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) is:

- either `docker run -v "$PWD/test":"/test" our-docker`
  (`-v` being the short form of `--volume`)
- or `docker run --mount type=bind,source="$PWD/test",target="/test" our-docker`

(*Note:* I replaced above `"$(pwd)"` with the special shell variable `"$PWD"` which avoids spinning yet another process.)

Next, you cannot just append the line `/test/check.sh` after the `docker run` line because you precisely need to run that command *within the context of `docker run`*. To this aim, you may want to use the pattern I proposed in this other SO thread: [How do I set docker-credential-ecr-login in my PATH before anything else in GitLab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690459/9164010) (which contains more details/remarks about `set -e`, quotes and shell escaping in the context of that pattern).

#### Wrap-up

More precisely, could you try the following adaptation of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`? (I've added some `ls` commands that should help debugging your configuration):

```
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - docker info

# Build the docker image
build:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login docker.example.com -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker build -t our-docker .
    - docker save our-docker > our-docker.tar
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - our-docker.tar
    expire_in: 1 week
  stage: build

test:
  image: docker:latest
  # note: use /bin/sh below as this image doesn't provide /bin/bash
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker load < our-docker.tar
    - echo "$PWD"
    - ls
    - ls -Rhal test
    - |
      docker run --rm -v "$PWD/test":"/test" our-docker /bin/sh -c "
        set -ex
        ls -Rhal /test
        /test/check.sh
      "
  stage: test
```

Comment: @JehadNasser did you get a chance to test that approach?

Comment: I am testing right now, I was busy the whole week, thanks a lot, will keep you posted ^_^.

Comment: /bin/sh: /test/check.sh: not found !! same probelm

Comment: @JehadNasser ok but I suspect that the remaining problem you observe is just a path issue. FYI I've updated my answer to add some `ls` commands that should help you figure out what's happening: if the first `ls -Rhal test` command return  "No such file or directory", that would mean that the `-v "$PWD/test":"/test"` command is wrong and should be replaced with `-v "$PWD":"/test"` or `-v "$PWD/another-existing-folder-containing-check.sh":"/test"`

Comment: I deleted everything, and tried to follow the gitlab documentation to mount a shared volume between the host & image & service(dind). But even copy/paste of the docs example is showing nothing when I `ls -a` inside the dir after the `touch file`!! This make me dig into my runner configurations.. do you know a good documentation about how the host & image & services interact with each other in the networking and filesystem wise?? Thanks a lot

Comment: @JehadNasser apart from https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#volumes-in-the-runnersdocker-section , I don't know some other good reference… but it seems you're now asking for a different question? I mean, in your original post you didn't mention using a custom gitlab runner configuration, while the approach I suggested should work on gitlab.com… so you might want to post another question with more details about your last comment? (e.g., which docs example (URL) you were talking about, where you ran `touch file` and `ls -a`, etc.)

Comment: if fact it's the same issue, if I mounted right, then the script is exist, then I can run it, but now the file is not exist, so changing the entrypoint is irrelevant unless the mounting issue fixed. This docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-workflow-with-docker-executor

Comment: also here the fix is explained very well, of course the official docs mention this link too: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/41227